# Programmatically display outlook desktop alert

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

Is it possible for an addin to trigger a desktop alert?

I am developing an addon for outlook 2013 and I want to display a desktop alert in some cases.

Does anyone know a way?

**Edit**

The outlook desktop alert is the notification that pops up when a message arrives, (unless a rule specifically turns it off).

File > Mail > 'Display Desktop alert'

It is not a message box, it is a alert that pops up specifically when a new message arrives, when multiple messages arrive the desktop alert displays "Multiple emails" messages.

Comment: @Meehow, That's a message box, not a desktop alert.

Comment: that's right, so what did google tell you about creating desktop alerts using C#?

Comment: @Meehow, Lol, I see you deleted your comment, I was responding to what you said, (your deleted comment was telling me to use "MessageBox.Show()"). My response was simply telling you that desktop alert is not the same as a MessageBox.Show().

Comment: Take a look at [`NotifyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You may need to host a hidden form to contain it, but that should be possible from winthin Outlook with a little case to run on Outlook's UI thread.

Comment: I added an explanation of Outlook Desktop alerts vs MessageBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

The new mail desktop alert that Outlook uses cannot be customized or integrated with via a custom solution.  If you want to throw your own alert, you will have to hook into the Outlook.Application.NewMail or [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686.aspx) events to trap when an new email has been delivered and display your custom UI.  You can use the .NET NotifyIcon component or use something fancier like the [AlertControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5395) from DevExpress.